# Istio Gateway With multiple ports | service is responding only on port 80

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Hey so I configured gateway for port 80 and 8083 for same domain i-e `example.com`. Now when I create attributes using below config file everything get up and running.

**issue is I am using `8083` in service and virtualService but I get response from service at `80` where on `8083` getting connection timeout.**

Unable to understand why service is responding on 80 not 8083. I want to keep both ports in gateway but when define in service and ingress port 8083 it should response on specifically on 8083.

Would appreciate your feedback in this.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  my.databag.1: need_triage
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-service-env-variables
  namespace: api

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-service
  name: my-service-service-deployment
  namespace: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges: 0.0.0.0/0
      labels:
        app: my-service-service-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: my.variable
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: my_token
              name: my.variable
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: my-service-env-variables
        image: imaagepath:tag
        name: my-service-pod
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: mysvcport
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 700m
            memory: 1.8Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1.7Gi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: api
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8083
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: mysvcport
  selector:
    app: my-service-service-deployment

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
  namespace: api
spec:
  gateways:
  - http-gateway
  hosts:
  - my-service.example.com
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: my-service
        port:
          number: 8083
---
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
  kind: Gateway
  metadata:
    clusterName: ""
    creationTimestamp: 2018-11-07T13:17:00Z
    name: http-gateway
    namespace: api
    resourceVersion: "11778445"
    selfLink: /apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/api/gateways/http-gateway
    uid: 694f66a4-e28f-11e8-bc21-0ac9e31187a0
  spec:
    selector:
      istio: ingressgateway
    servers:
    - hosts:
      - '*.example.com'
      port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
    - hosts:
      - '*.example.com'
      port:
        name: tomcat-http
        number: 8083
        protocol: HTTP
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Two issues with your configuration:

1. You have to call your port `http-tomcat` and not `tomcat-http`, see [Istio requirements for named ports](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/spec-requirements/)
2. In order to enable ingress on port 8083, you have to redeploy the `istio-ingressgateway` service, with the port 8083 added:

   `helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio/ --name istio-ingressgateway \
   --namespace istio-system -x charts/gateways/templates/service.yaml \
   --set gateways.istio-egressgateway.enabled=false \
   --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.ports[0].port=80 \
   --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.ports[0].name=http \
   --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.ports[1].port=443 \
   --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.ports[1].name=https \
   --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.ports[2].port=8083 \
   --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.ports[2].name=http-tomcat \
   | kubectl apply -f -`

Having said that, do you really have to enable ingress access to the port 8083? You can define some path in the `VirtualService` for the port 80, e.g. /tomcat/* and direct the incoming traffic from the port 80 to your service on the port 8083.

Comment: Hey thanks for response and apologies for getting it back this late. so rather creating `istio-ingressgateway` service from scratch I edited service using `kubectl edit` 
Now this is how istio-gateway service looks like 

- name: http-tomcat
    nodePort: 30541
    port: 8083
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8083

Also updated gateway of specific namespace as `http-tomcat` with port 8084 but still same issue service is responding on port 80 but not on 8083

Comment: You should also name the service port, see Istio requirements for named ports - https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/spec-requirements/ .